# Simple Keypress Event Not working for textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox in which i written keypress function for the Enter Key, which should show alert.

Here is my html and script.

Here is my Textbox :

```
<li>
<input type="text" class="fi_top" placeholder="Howdy" id="howdy" value="">
</li>
```

And inside the page i have

Script :

```
$( "#howdy" ).keypress(function( event ) 
{
  if ( event.which == 13 ) {
  alert('okay');
}
});
```

But i am not getting alert while i press enter at the textbox.

What is the mistake i am doing and how can i fix this ?

Comment: try using event.keyCode == 13

Comment: I tried just now that tooo.. But not working :(

Comment: keyCode with C in caps. See my answer.

Comment: are you adding the element in runtime or is it loaded with the page content

Comment: You code is working, have you included the jquery library to your page. here is working fiddle by your code http://jsfiddle.net/v3fggs1w/

Comment: Your code is working check this link http://jsfiddle.net/gvd9wzLk/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you are adding this element dynamically in the HTML and .keypress will only work on pre loaded elements. jQuery has provided $(document).on for dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#howdy", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.which == '13') {
       //Do your work
    }
});
```

Comment: It works great ! May i know the reason why it didn't worked ??

Answer (score 1):

Hey you should try `keypress` event like this

```
$("#howdy").keypress(function() {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
        callAjaxGetJoiningDate($(this).val());
        event.preventDefault()
    }
 });
```

Comment: i tried this $('#howdy').keyup(function() {
 alert('okay');
  
 }); But not working

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
event.KeyCode == 13
```

**JS Code:**

```
$( "#howdy" ).keypress(function( event ) 
{
  if ( event.keyCode == 13 ) {
  alert('okay');
}
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hh2wmbvq/)

Comment: keyCode does not work in old IE, so you should use both.

Comment: It's working good in fiddle, but in my code it fails, i am searching for that reason sri

Comment: @Bizz  Could you mention your browser name and version ?

Comment: Its late firefox , but the code is in seperate .js page, is that matters ?

Answer (score 1):

Place this in document.ready block, so that it will trigger after whole dom will load. Eventually mark your script with defer attribute.

You should use both which and keyCode , bacause they don't work on all browsers.

```
$( "#howdy" ).keypress(function( event ) 
{
  if ( event.which == 13 || event.keyCode == 13) {
  alert('okay');
}
});
```